# Objective C , base64 string to image not showing

Tags: ios, string, image, base64, decode

I need to convert encoded base64 string to image Im using this code:

```
- (UIImage *)decodeBase64ToImage:(NSString *)strEncodeData {
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncodeData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
    return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

// but it only show piece of picture :(

IN Android I'm using this code :

```
public static Bitmap byteToImage(String byteArray)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(byteArray,Base64.NO_WRAP);
            InputStream inputStream  = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
            bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("byteToImage.EROOR.........", e.getMessage());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Any good idea or solution?

Comment: What is your Android code?

Comment: I use Nick Lockwood's Base64 category: https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64

Comment: Your code looks good. Is your base64 image format right ?

Comment: Try encoding then decode an image. Encode with `return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the my android code. Its working well !

```
public static Bitmap byteToImage(String byteArray)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(byteArray,Base64.NO_WRAP);
            InputStream inputStream  = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
            bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("byteToImage.EROOR.........", e.getMessage());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: please remove this answer